# .NET 4.7.2 System.Text.Json missing dependency

Tags: c#, dll, dependencies, assembly-binding-redirect

I'm creating dll containg chart, to send data to control I'm using JSON format.
I added NuGet package System.Text.Json And I can compile it and test on this functionality pass.

However, after I use it in aplication (SCADA system with VBA underneath) I got error:

> Could not load file or assembly ‘System.Buffers, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture, neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51’, or one of its dependencies. System cannot find the file specified.

I noticed that System.Buffers is not visible in Dependencies, but it's adden in file app.config in my project. After compile System.Buffer.dll appears in output folder so I copied it to target aplication too.

I found some topics about Binding Redirection causing similar problem, but could solve it.

Comment: A net application looks for dlls in a few locations and if the dll is not in one of these locations the file will not be found.  Not all dlls are the same so most likely a vba dll will not work or you need to use like a c++ dll and use DllImport

Comment: Update: After puting dll into program instalation folder (as specified in help topic) I got Error: Could not load file or assembly ‘System.Buffers, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture, neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51’, or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT 0x80131040).

Comment: @jdweng This scada system have ability to run .net dlls writen in C# or VB.NET i also installed .NET Framework on target computer. Shouldn't it use DLLs thank i copied or dlls form .Net Framework instalation folder?

Comment: There are two main types of dll 1) Manged dll that work with c# in Net 2) Un-managed COM dlls.  dll in the c:\windows\system32 folder are un-managed.Any exception that starts with 0x8 are errors caused by accessing memory that you do not have the privilege to access.So null pointer will give these errors or using unmanaged dll in a managed C# application.You cannot copy files from the Framework folder and simply put on another machine.A lot of Framework dll are simple wrappers that call Windows System 32 dlls.A c# application will only work on another machine if the same version of Net exists.

Comment: @jdweng I have the same version of .NET (4.8) on both computers. I copied dlls that were created in /bin/Debug folder in my project.

Comment: Open the csproj file with notepad and verify the path to the files are correct.  If it is VBA code then some of the dlls are in the c:\program File folder under the version of Office that is installed.  You may have a different version of office.

Answer (score 1):

I'm building a Windows Forms app with a .Net Standard 2.0 class library. For me, adding the `System.Text.Json` Nuget to the Windows Forms app as well as to the class library fixed the issue